# Drawing pictures in JFRame

Tags: java, swing

) please help to solve the problem. I'm doing a little game and paint it a coin) to the player went and gathered them.

Here's how the process of gathering (that's code):

```
  if (x + w3 == 190) {
                coins++;
                mon = null;
            } else {
                g.drawImage(mon, 190 - x, 265, wm, hm, this);
            }
```

Where 190 - is the position where the coin

Where x + w3 the coordinates of the player

That is, when the coordinates of touch coin disappear,but along with this coin disappear, and others, in fact - mon = null;

What should I do? really for each coin to make your picture?

thanks in advance.

**UPD**

All Code:

```
package GameTs;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Game extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final String NAME = "DrakGo Game";
    public static final int WIDTH = 500;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 460;

    private static final int MAP_SIZE_X = 100;
    private Image img;
    private Image img2;
    private Image mon;
    private Image mon2;
    private Image mon3;
    private Image pl;
    private Image mag;
    private Image drak;
    private Input input = new Input(this);
    static JFrame frame;
    static int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int xp = 110;
    int yp = 180;
    int coins = 0;
    URL url4;
    URL url7;

    public Game() {
        URL url2 = getClass().getResource("images/Grass.png");
        img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url2);

        URL url = getClass().getResource("images/Cloud.png");
        img2 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url);

        URL url3 = getClass().getResource("images/Mon.png");//THIS
        mon = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url3);

        mon2 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url3);//THIS
        mon3 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url3);//THIS

        url4 = getClass().getResource("images/Right_Pic1.png");
        URL url5 = getClass().getResource("images/Mag.png");
        URL url6 = getClass().getResource("images/Dr.png");
        url7 = getClass().getResource("images/Right_Pic2.png");

        pl = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url4);
        mag = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url5);
        drak = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url6);

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        render(g);
        repaint();
    }

    private void move(Graphics g) {
        /*
         * if (input.left) { x--; if (x == -1) { x++; }
         * 
         * }
         */
        if (input.right) {
            x++;
            if (x == -1) {
                x--;
            }
            if ((x % 2) == 0) {
                pl = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url7);
            } else {
                pl = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url4);
            }
        }

    }

    public void render(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        move(g);

        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 360);

        int w = 180;
        int h = 180;

        for (int i = 0; i < MAP_SIZE_X * 2; i++) {
            g.drawImage(img, i * w - x, 260, (int) w, (int) h, this);
        }

        int w2 = 90;
        int h2 = 50;

        for (int c = 0; c < MAP_SIZE_X * 100; c += 200) {
            g.drawImage(img2, 100 + c - x, 70, w2, h2, this);

        }

        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment
                .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        Font[] allFonts = ge.getAllFonts();
        Font font = allFonts[4].deriveFont(30.0F);
        g.setFont(font);
        g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        g.drawString("DrakGo - Game", 10, 40);
        g.drawString("X: " + x, 300, 40);
        g.drawString("Coins: " + coins, 400, 40);

        int w3 = 50;
        int h3 = 50;

        int wm = 30;
        int hm = 30;
        if (x + w3 == 190) {
            coins++;
            mon = null;
        } else {
            g.drawImage(mon, 190 - x, 265, wm, hm, this);
        }

            //THIS!!!!!!!
        if (x + w3 == 350) {
            coins++;
            mon2 = null;
        } else {
            g.drawImage(mon2, 350 - x, 265, wm, hm, this);
        }

        if (x + w3 == 650) {
            coins++;
            mon3 = null;
        } else {
            g.drawImage(mon3, 650 - x, 265, wm, hm, this);
        }

        int w4 = 50;
        int h4 = 50;

        if (x + w3 == 3500) {
            drak = null;
        } else {
            g.drawImage(drak, 3500 - x, 260, w4, h4, this);
        }

        g.drawImage(mag, 1000 - x, 260, w3, h3, this);

        g.drawImage(pl, 0, 260, w3, h3, this);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game game = new Game();
        game.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame = new JFrame(NAME);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.add(game);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    }
}
```

Comment: This snippet (although very hard to guess the context) seems awfully wrong. You are mixing two very different things: your model (the number of coins gathered) and drawing (paint to a `Graphics` object). These belong to different methods (and even often to different classes). Where does `g` come from? Show us the rest of your code. Try to make an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 0):

Remove this:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    render(g);
    repaint();
}
```

Instead use this:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    render(g);
}
```

Also change:

```
public void render(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    move(g);
    // ..
```

To:

```
public void render(Graphics g) {
    move(g);
    // ..
```

---

Both methods as they were, would tend to cause an infinite loop.